# Making an user fill more data in a text area?

Tags: user-engagement

I am currently working on a complete revamp of an application that helps in Knowledge management. The main problem was the older system was just a form capturing which was quite tedious. This information which is to be filled would be used later to help other people facing the same problem. (the information captured was how to solve a problem.)

What I am trying to solve is to make people fill more data so that it can be categorized and used properly. Any suggestions on how to make people fill more and not make it tedious?

Ex : A person has worked on an issue and later needs to fill saying what all steps that person took to solve the issue. This way if someone else has a similar issue this might come up as a suggestion. If the first person has not filled up clearly and properly this might not be useful to the second person at all.

Comment: The problem you are describing is very unclear. What kind of data are we talking about? What does the current form look like?

Comment: Hi! Have you tried to reward them with something? Badges, points etc? Just search gamification+"your topic". There is also a good gamification course in coursera.org. ;)

Comment: @BartGijssens i have added an example if that helps.

Comment: @davidtoltesy Gamification is something i am looking at currently. I was also thinking about having the other people in the system vote up or vote down on the data that is entered with respect to if it was useful or was unclear.

Comment: People must be motivated. Simple asking them to help is not working in a long term. It is ok on social media sites. They will share your posts but if you are looking for a sustainable solution, you should add some extra, like points, levels etc. Most of the CMS/Forum systems have options to reward users... and not by chance. A colored badge or a star can add difference. Gamification doesn't mean that you have to add lot's of game elements. It can also help with small tricks to motivate your users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some users may not know what info they are suppose to put in. If you know ahead of time the type of info a field is suppose to have it helps set the expectation. So consider putting a placeholder info into the textbox that acts like a template...

`What steps did you take to solve the issue?
* Step 1
* Step 2
* Step 3`

Comment: This would actually help. Breaking down the questions into the data that I want and then using it later :)